# Android service pausing on certain device

Tags: android, android-service, android-6.0-marshmallow

My app uses a service which I have designed. Problem is the app works fine on some phones (like Gionee, Asus phones) but does not work on Nexus, One Plus or Moto. On theses devices the service pauses on minimising the app. These are my corresponding classes.

```
public class Sync extends AppCompatActivity {
Button listen;
Button stopListen;

SyncService syncService;
boolean syncServiceBound = false;


/* CreateActivity */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_discoverer);

    /*
    Initialise
     */

    listen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_listen);
    stopListen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop_listener);
    /*
     * Check if device is connected via wifi
     */
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if(networkInfo.isConnected()){
        displayToast("Connected via wifi");
    }else{
        displayToast("Not connected");
    }


    /**
     * Start broadcasting if device is not already broadcasting
     * Start listening for broadcasts if not already listening
     */

    listen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent syncServiceIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SyncService.class);
            bindService(syncServiceIntent, syncServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            startService(syncServiceIntent);
            startPeerListUIThread();
        }
    });

    stopListen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent syncServiceIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SyncService.class);
            if(syncServiceBound) {
                unbindService(syncServiceConnection);
            }
            syncServiceBound = false;
            stopService(syncServiceIntent);
            stopPeerListUIThread();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    unbindService(syncServiceConnection);
    super.onDestroy();
}

private ServiceConnection syncServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        SyncService.SyncServiceBinder binder = (SyncService.SyncServiceBinder) service;
        syncService = binder.getService();
        syncServiceBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        syncServiceBound = false;
    }
};

}
```

and

```
public class SyncService extends Service {

private final IBinder syncServiceBinder = new SyncServiceBinder();

public SyncService() {
    // initialise 
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    // do something
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return syncServiceBinder;
}


@Override
public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
    // do something 
    return super.stopService(name);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
// do something
    super.onDestroy();
}

public class SyncServiceBinder extends Binder {
    SyncService getService() {
        // Return this instance of SyncService so activity can call public methods
        return SyncService.this;
    }
}


}
```

Initially I thought using android M was the problem (the doze feature may have been interfering) but is not the case apparently.

Comment: How exactly does it not work? You have to describe the exact problem  otherwise no one can help you. Nexus devices and the software on them is a reference for how things are supposed to work on Android. That it doesn't work on them is a bad sign right from the start.

Comment: @XaverKapeller the service pauses on minimising the app